# Hyperplanes and sublattices correspondence

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, finite-fields, lattices-in-lie-groups

I struggled to understand the first 3 lines of this paragraph (see linked image), can someone elaborate?
Not sure what is the inverse image in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and how to understand the corresponding sublattice $L_H$ $\subset \mathbb{Z}^2$  in case for example $a$, $b$ are not both $0$ and
$$
H = \bigl\{ (x, y)\in (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^2: ax+by \equiv c\pmod p \bigr\}
$$

(I'm only interested in the case $n=2$ and $j=1$, using the paragraph's notations).
If someone can give an example to explain how this correspondence works and then to treat the "general case", i.e., to find $L_H$ for the $H$ I wrote above, it would be very appreciated.

[image]

This paragraph is from page 8 of this article: [https://www.math.ias.edu/~akshay/research/andreas.pdf](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Eakshay/research/andreas.pdf)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to be more concrete now

Comment: It forms a lattice. You can sort of think of them the boundaries of the periodic structure. Do you understand how the homomorphism given by $\mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$ has a lattice for a kernel? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group)

Comment: Do you mean the reduction $\mod p$? I'm not sure why the kernel is a lattice, can you elaborate please?

Comment: @CyclotomicField you mean the lattice with basis which is the collection of vectors $(0,...,p,0...,0)$ (i.e. $p$ in the $i$th coordinate and $0$ in the other coordinates) for example?

Comment: Please do not use pictures of symbols for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched, and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to have a few relevant pictures on my laptop in a folder dedicated to a suitable course in algebra, so I will share.

---

As commented by @CyclotomicField, this is all about the preimages of the natural projection (modulo $p$) $\pi:\Bbb{Z}^2\to(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^2$. This is a homomorphism of groups, so the preimage of a subgroup is necessarily a subgroup. As a finitely generated subgroup of a free abelian group, it is then necessarily a free abelian group itself. Hence it is also lattice.

What's going on here is an instance of *the correspondence theorem* giving a bijection between subgroups $H$ of $(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^2$ and the collection of such subgroups $M$ of $\Bbb{Z}^2$ that contain $p\Bbb{Z}^2$. The correspondence is via $M=\pi^{-1}(H)$. Sometimes the term *lattice* is reserved for certain subgroups $\Lambda$ of $\Bbb{R}^n$ (here obviously $n=2$ only). Namely the discrete, full rank, free abelian groups. But your source seems to also call cosets of such subgroups $\lambda+\vec{x}\subseteq\Bbb{Z}^2$ also lattices. This is fine (geometrically), but may explain the confusion. More precisely, the choice $c=0$ corresponds to the subgroup $\Lambda$ itself, and non-zero choices to its cosets.

The first picture is about the case $p=2$, $a=b=1$. Here
$$H=\{(\overline{x},\overline{y})\in\Bbb{Z}_2^2\mid \overline{x}+\overline{y}=\overline{0}\}.$$
The preimage $\pi^{-1}(H)$ then consists of the lattice points $(x,y)$ such that $x+y$ is even. Those are marked red. The coset corresponding to $c=1$ (in other words, odd $x+y$) is marked blue.

[image]

The second picture is about $p=5$ and the case where $H=\langle (\overline{2},\overline{1})\rangle$. In other words, $H$ consists of the solutions of
$x-2y=0$ inside $\Bbb{Z}_5^2$. This time $\pi^{-1}(H)$ (so $c=0$) is marked with blue dots, the
coset $c=1$ with red dots, the coset $c=2$ green, the coset $c=3$ grey, and the coset $c=4$ yellow.

[image]

I apologize to viewers suffering from a form of color-blindness that makes the image less useful. I'm open to suggestions for other ways of visually distinguishing the cosets.

Comment: Yes, I think this is what confused me. The image is also helping to understand the meaning of "coset" in this case, although your explanation is enough for me.

Comment: Glad to hear that.  I was actually a bit surprised to see non-zero $c$ allowed in the definition, but this is what it corresponds to. I have never seriously studied those Hecke operators, but having pictures like this in mind helped me at one seminar. There will be more choices for the types of lattices, when you only require $\Lambda$ to contain $p^2\Bbb{Z}^2$ (or the scaled equivalent).  IIRC that came into play, when iterates of $T_p$ were used.